# Getting a JavaScript Error when calling prompt method from page-object-gem

Tags: page-object-gem

```
Scenario: Testing with prompt popups
Given I am on the frames page
When I popup the prompt and enter "Jared Gatorboy"
  SyntaxError: missing ; before statement (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError)
  ./features/support/pages/frames_page.rb:35:in `block in prompt_value'
  ./features/support/pages/frames_page.rb:34:in `prompt_value'
  ./features/step_definitions/web01_steps.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  ./features/step_definitions/web01_steps.rb:34:in `/^I popup the prompt and enter "(.*?)"$/'
  features/web01.feature:20:in `When I popup the prompt and enter "Jared Gatorboy"'
Then the message from the prompt should read "enter your name"
And the default value from the prompt should be "John Doe"
```

./features/support/pages/frames_page.rb

```
def prompt_value(value)
in_frame(:id => 'frame_3') do |frame|
  @prompt_response = prompt(value, frame) do
    button_element(:id => 'prompt_button', :frame => frame).click
  end 
 end
 @prompt_response
end
```

./features/step_definitions/web01_steps.rb

```
When(/^I popup the prompt and enter "(.*?)"$/) do |value_to_enter|
 on_page(FramesPage) do |page|
  @prompt_response = page.prompt_value(value_to_enter)
 end
end
```

[App URL](http://puppies.herokuapp.com/frames.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me what browser and driver you are using?  In the page-object test suite there is a test that uses this page.  Here is the step definition

```
When /^I trigger a prompt within a frame$/ do
  @page.in_frame(:id => 'frame_3') do |frame|
    @msg = @page.prompt("Cheezy", frame) do
      @page.button_element(:id => 'prompt_button', :frame => frame).click
    end
  end
end
```

It looks to be the identical logic you have in your steps and the tests work with the latest firefox using both selenium-webdriver and watir-webdriver as the driver.